# Массив и localStorage. Как извлечь из памяти случайные элементы массива и записать их в новый?

Tags: javascript, массивы, localstorage

Нужно создать случайный одномерный массив М1 размерностью 20. Записать данные массива в Web Storage. Извлечь из памяти случайные числа и записать их в массив М2 и отсортировать. Вывести на страницу 2 массива для сравнения.

Помогите именно с извлечением случайных чисел из памяти.

Answer (score 0):

```
function rand(a, b){let r=a+Math.random()*(b+1-a);return Math.floor(r);} //Генератор случайных чисел
for (var i = 0; i<20; i++){
    localStorage.setItem(i, rand(1,90)); //Заполняем локальное хранилище случайными числами с ключем от 0 до 20
}
var randNums = [];
for (var i = 0; i<20; i++){
   randNums.push(localStorage.getItem(rand(1,20))); //Извлекаем 20 случайных чисел из локального хранилища и вносим в randNums
}
console.log(randNums)
```